# How do I access onMerge, onReplace, onRemove functions for a Rich Text component in Gutenberg block code?

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to make a Gutenberg block with a RichText component so that it will work like a paragraph, in that when there are two next to each other hitting backspace will merge them.

There seems to be a function at `line 314` of `block-editor/src/components/block-list/block.js` but I can't figure out how to access it from my block code.

So far I have:

````js
( function( blocks, editor, blockEditor, element, i18n ) {
    /** IMPORTANT VARS!!! **/
    var el = element.createElement;
    var RichText = blockEditor.RichText;
    var createBlock = blocks.createBlock;
    var __ = i18n.__;

    blocks.registerBlockType( 'snt/my-paragraph', {
        title: 'My Paragraph',
        icon: 'thumbs-up',
        category: 'common',

        attributes: {
            content: {
                type: 'srting',
                source: 'children',
                selector: 'h3',
                default: ''
            }
        },

        edit: function( props ) {
            function onChangeContent( newContent ) {
                props.setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
            }

            function onSplitContent( value ) {

                if ( ! value ) {
                    return createBlock( 'core/paragraph' );
                }

                return createBlock( 'snt/my-paragraph', {
                    ...props.attributes,
                    content: value,
                } );

            }
console.log(props);
            return el(
                RichText,
                {
                    tagName: 'h3',
                    onChange: onChangeContent,
                    placeholder: __('Enter some text here...'),
                    keepPlaceholderOnFocus: false,
                    multiline: false,
                    onSplit: onSplitContent,
                    onReplace: props.onReplace,
                    onRemove: props.onReplace ? () => props.onReplace( [] ) : undefined,
                    onMerge: props.mergeBlocks,
                    value: props.attributes.content 
                }
            )
        },

        save: function( props ) {
            return el( RichText.Content, {
                tagName: 'h3', 
                value: props.attributes.content,
                className: props.className
            } );
        },
    } );
}(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.editor,
    window.wp.blockEditor,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.i18n
) );```
````

I can't help think I have missed something obvious. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered instead just having child blocks? That way you would have real paragraph blocks that do what you wanted automatically because that's how paragraph blocks are meant to work. It sounds like you wanted to add an option or a style to the paragraph block, but rather than adding an option, or a block style, you registered a whole new block type

Comment: Hello Tom. This is more an exercise in learning how to code blocks, and understanding the properties of the RichText component. There is not really a final use that I have in mind. Since Gutenberg was introduced I have been trying to get to grips with ES6, React and blocks. This is a very slow and painful journey.

Comment: If you're learning, I'd look into `wp scripts` and JSX, wp scripts will build your code and give you PHP files with arrays for the dependencies your script needs, handle converting components into the normal javascript, etc. As for those functions, they're documented with examples here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/a83cb80095795fe7998212f287a9a68a8e318a77/packages/block-editor/src/components/editable-text/README.md#L32

Comment: the functions onSplit, onReplace, onRemove, onMerge are passed to your component in props.